# Can anyone tell me what error msg "line 1182 in parse" means when I'm trying to parse and xml in python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, url, elementtree

This is the code that results in an error message:

```
import urllib
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

url = raw_input('Enter URL:')

urlhandle = urllib.urlopen(url)

data = urlhandle.read()

tree = ET.parse(data)
```

The error:

[image: error msg screenshot]

I'm new to python. I did read documentation and a couple of tutorials, but clearly I still have done something wrong.  I don't believe it is the xml file itself because it does this to two different xml files.

Comment: This is called a traceback. See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html for an explanation of what it means.

Comment: Please post the actual text of that error instead of an image. That way others can find it when searching for it.

Comment: Pass the response not the content `tree = ET.parse(urllib.urlopen(url))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using ElementTree's [`fromstring()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring):

```
import urllib
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

url = raw_input('Enter URL:')
# http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml?edition=int

urlhandle = urllib.urlopen(url)    
data = urlhandle.read()

tree = ET.fromstring(data)

print ET.tostring(tree, encoding='utf8', method='xml')
```

Comment: Great! Please accept the most helpful answer to confirm resolution.

Answer (score 1):

`data` is a reference to the XML content as a string, but the [`parse()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.parse) function expects a filename or [file object](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-file-object) as argument. That's why there is an an error.

`urlhandle` is a file object, so `tree = ET.parse(urlhandle)` should work for you.

Comment: Just a note to anyone searching this and to mzjn, this worked equally well with the other option, but I can only 'check' one response (as a complete newb, I find this odd since even with minimal experience I find there are usually multiple ways to create functional code). Anyway, this worked :-)

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that your code is trying to open a file, who's name is stored in the variable source.

It's failing to open that file (IOError) because the variable source contains a bunch of XML, not a file name.

Comment: Thanks Danielle. I thought the way I dealt with getting the URL, opening it and then parsing it looked clumsy, but I could not find the right way to do it.  Is there a single line syntax that can take input and then parse it as an xml?

Comment: You're using source twice, once as the filename, then clobbering it with the new file handle. Try something like inFile = open(source, "rb")

Comment: No, this is misleading. `source` comes from the source code of the ElementTree library, not from the OP's code.